# ExtJS 3.4 - Check for recently added items in a store

Tags: extjs

So I was messing around trying to figure out the best way to find recently added items to a store. To put it into context, I have a grid which data is bound to such store. This store is filled with data from the server side. It also has an "add" button that adds these new records. Whenever a user clicks a line in the grid, I want a different behaviour for saved records and newly created ones. I know I can check if an item has been added recently with

```
myStore.data.itemAt(0).newRecord //Uses index
```

or

```
myStore.data.item(1).newRecord //Uses key; "1" is just for demonstration purposes
```

However, if the item was added previously to the store (in other words, the data came from the server side), newRecord will return undefined (as a matter of fact, there is no such property in a MixedCollection item that has already been "commited"). Of course this can be easily side-stepped, but will end up looking more like an ugly workaround than anything else.

Is there any better way to do it? I think I'll mess around with the grid methods themselves in order to see if I can figure something out, but any pointers are welcome.

Comment: you should have an unique id inside the database. When store loaded, check that record. If the value, let's say `0`, do something, otherwise do another thing. When user click the add button, change this value with `1`.

Comment: That would sort of break down the whole structure, but thanks anyway. I'll leave it as it is for the time being.